# Server messages are not sent immediately

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to program a small messenger using Python socket programming and Tkinter. The message one client sends to the server must be sent immediately to all the clients (accepted sockets). But, what is happening in my code is that the server stores all the messages sent from other clients in some sort of buffer and sends it all together when that client sends some message.

I have provided an image to make it clear:

[image]

My client code looks like this:

```
s.settimeout(1)
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            insertText(2, data.decode('utf-8'))
        except socket.timeout as e:
            break
    base.mainloop()
```

My server code is like:

```
def open_conn_thread(conn, addr):
# conn.sendall(str.encode('this is test'))
reply = ''
if addr not in clients:
    clients.append(conn)
    print(clients)
while True:
    data= conn.recv(4096)
    reply =  data.decode('utf-8')
    reply = 'Server Output: ' + reply
    for c in clients:
        print('sending to : ' , c)
        c.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    if not data:
        break
conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to : ' , addr)
    start_new_thread(open_conn_thread,(conn,addr))
```